# How do I fix this expected Identifier error in C?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, identifier

I keep getting an “expected identifier or “(“ error but I can’t seem to find a way to solve this. My code is attached [Screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWJGH.jpg)

I’ve read around that it could be caused by a lack of function name / definition. I already have that, so i’m not sure what else to check as I am self learning using CS50

Code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float half(float bill, float tax, int tip); //function declaration

int main(void)

    {
        float bill_amount = get_float("Bill before tax and tip: ");
        float tax_percent = get_float("Sale Tax Percent: ");
        int tip_percent = get_int("Tip percent: ");

        printf("You will owe $%.2f each!\n", half(bill_amount, tax_percent, tip_percent)); //function call
    }


float half(float bill, float tax, int tip); //function definition
    {
        float result, plus_tax;
        float bill = bill_amount;
        float tax = tax_amount / 100;
        int tip = tip_percent / 100;
        plus_tax = bill + bill * tax;
        result = plus_tax + plus_tax * tip;
        return(result);
    }
```

Update: Thanks for the comments. I have updated my code as seen below.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float half(float bill, float tax, int tip); //function declaration

int main(void)
{
    float bill_amount = get_float("Bill before tax and tip: ");
    float tax_percent = get_float("Sale Tax Percent: ");
    int tip_percent = get_int("Tip percent: ");

    printf("You will owe $%.2f each!\n", half(bill_amount, tax_percent, tip_percent)); //function call
}


float half(float bill, float tax, int tip) //function definition
{
    float result, plus_tax;
    plus_tax = bill + bill * (tax / 100);
    result = (plus_tax + plus_tax * (tip / 100))/2;
    return(result);
}
```

Comment: Please post the code here, not the link to screenshot.

Comment: In line 19, what is `bill_amount`? Think about the scope where the variable defined in line 8 is visible and where not.

Comment: For future questions please provide complete and exact error message in your question. Use copy&paste (same as with the code, any input, output and expected output) to add as formatted text. Unless you are asking about visual details of some window etc, never post pictures of text. No one can run your picture through the compiler or debugger

Comment: `float bill = bill_amount;` besides using an identifier that is not defined in that scope, you are defining a new variable `bill` that hides the one from your parameter list. That is called shadowing. You should never do this.

Comment: Thanks! I assumed I had to equal the new variable to the one in the main program, but I get that it is out of scope. I have amended this and will repost my code which runs now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of `float half(float bill, float tax, int tip);` should not be followed by a semicolon.
You end function prototype with semicolon on declaration, not on definition.
Also, the `bill_amount`, `tax_amount`, `tip_pourcent` variables in `half` function should have been renamed to the function's argument matching names (ie `bill`, `tax` and `tip`)

Comment: Please avoid answering "picture of code" questions, not to encourage more of such. And even if this was posted as text, "stray semicolon" etc questions are simple typos that hold no value to future readers, so such questions should be closed not answered.

Comment: @Lundin legit comment :)